# Append text to end of line not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to read lines from a file and append string to it. But it's not appending correctly.

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE=$1
while IFS= read -r line
do
    line2="${line} &"
    echo $line2
done <$FILE
```

My input file contains

```
message
sample
text
```

expected output

```
message &
sample &
text &
```

But after executing script i am getting below output.

```
 &ssage
 &mple
 &xt
```

Why it's not appending string at the end ?

Comment: While your main issue is with CR characters in the input, see also here [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803), three common mistakes in shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 &ssage
 &mple
 &xt
```

The problem is your input file (apparently created in Windows) has CRLF line endings.

Fix it with `sed -i 's/\r//' file`

Comment: a LF would put the `&` on the next line ... the OP's text lines probably have CR only

Comment: @jsotola no, it is definitely CRLF. You would only get a final line with `&` if there was an additional LF after the final CRLF.

Comment: sed -i 's/\r//' file not works for me, i need to add sed -i.bak 's/\r//' file

Comment: @fuzzydrawings There is actually a tool `dos2unix` specifically designed to fix that issue; you might want to include it in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @fuzzydrawrings . `sed -i 's/\r//' $srcFile` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this.

I just ran it locally, and also made a version you can easily try on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    line2="${line} &"
    echo $line2
done <<EOM
message
sample
text
EOM
```

Output

```
message &
sample &
text &
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the input text file is a DOS text file.  This means that each line ends with a carriage-return character.  When outputted, this character brings the cursor back to the start of the line, which means that when `echo` outputs the space before `&`, it will be written to the beginning of the line.

You should convert the text file to Unix text format using a tool like `dos2unix`.

You also have issues with quoting in your shell code when you output the value of `$line2`.  Since you do not quote the variable expansion, the shell will split its value on spaces, tabs, and newlines to generate words.  These words will also undergo filename globbing before being passed as individual arguments to `echo`.  This means that any tab or set of more than one consecutive space in your input would be converted to single spaces and that any globbing pattern in the input that happens to match one or more existing filenames would be replaced by those filenames.  Try, for example, with a line of input with a single `*` on it.

The `echo` utility has a tendency to, under some circumstances, modify the data that it outputs (expanding `\n` into literal newlines, etc.), so if you want to preserve the literal data of the input, you should be using `printf` instead.

Reading text line by line in a shell loop is also a bit inefficient, and your task is better performed by tools such as `sed`,

```bsh
sed 's/$/ \&/' <"$1"
```

(replaces the end of the line with a space and an ampersand)

... or `awk`,

```bsh
awk '{ printf "%s &\n", $0 }' <"$1"
```

(outputs each line with space and `&` added; could also have used `print $0, "&"`).

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: See also `gawk -v RS='\r?\n' -v ORS=' &\n' 1` to convert CRLF or LF line delimiters to "& LF" ones

Comment: *"each line ends with a carriage-return character"* - that is not correct, each line ends with a line-feed character preceded by a carriage-return character. CRLF. You also don't need to install `dos2unix` for the simple task of removing carriage-returns from a text file.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings 1) Each _line_ of a DOS text file, as interpreted on a Unix system, does end with a carriage-return character. There is a carriage-return, and then the line-feed, and the line-feed constitutes the end of the line, but is not part of the line (a delimiter is not part of the data that it delimits). Any utility on any Unix system that reads _lines of text_ will read strings ended by carriage-returns when reading a DOS-formatted text file.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings 2) Yes, it's easy to remove all carriage-returns with `tr` or any other simple tool, but `dos2unix` was developed for that task.  By using `dos2unix`, you are guaranteed that any carriage-return that you wouldn't expect to remove, isn't removed.  This is _the_ utility that is made for converting text files from DOS or Windows systems for use on Unix.  The tool also automatically converts the text from common DOS/Windows encodings to encoding more commonly used on Unix.